# Creating OOP Callbacks

Tags: php, oop, callback, anonymous-function

I am trying to understand how to use anonymous functions with OOP callback methods. My class looks like this:

```
class Example
{
    protected $Callbacks = array();

    public function set(
        $foo,$bar
    ) {
        $this->Callbacks[$foo] = $bar;
    }

    public function get(
        $foo
    ) {
        return $this->Callbacks[$foo];
    }
}
```

To add a new callback I simply do something like:

```
$example = new Example;
$example->set(
     'example', function() {
         return 'hello';
     });
```

However, when I then want to use that function, nothing happens when I run this:

```
echo $example->get('example');
```

Can anyone help and possibly explain how to create callbacks in an OOP mannor?

Comment: That just retrieves the closure, but doesn't execute anything

Comment: Oh right, how could I get it to execute the function and echo the return? @PeeHaa

Comment: How do you normally execute a function?

Comment: so it would be something like `echo $example->get('example')();` ? @PeeHaa

Comment: Depending on your php version yes. Otherwise you will have to store the closure in a variable first.

Comment: That is brilliant and worked, I am on PHP 5.6 and it worked fine, appreciated! If you want to add an answer I'll hapilly mark it! @PeeHaa

Comment: I cannot find a dupe this fast, but you can answer it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call your functions like this:

```
echo $example->get('example')();
```

But I think it's ugly. You can also use magic methods for this purpose. But it's not the best practice too.

```
class Example
{
    protected $Callbacks = array();

    public function __set($name, $value)
    {
        $this->Callbacks[$name] = $value;
    }

    public function __call($name, array $arguments)
    {
        if (!isset($this->Callbacks[$name])) {
            trigger_error('Call to undefined method ' . get_class($this) . "::$name()", E_USER_ERROR);
        }
        return $this->Callbacks[$name]($arguments);
    }
}

$example = new Example();
$example->example = function() {
    return 'hello';
};

echo $example->example();
```

Comment: _But it's not the best practice too._ Does the manual say anything about how to use them when it comes to best practices? I don't see any bad practice here. It serves its purpose and magic methods clearly has the advantage when it comes to executing anonymous functions stored in the object. The part where it becomes a _bad practice_ is when it's not practically understood by other developers. Method `example` could be interpretate as a real method of class `Example`, if class `Example`s source becomes bigger it might be harder to debug. That's where the documentation kicks in.

Comment: I am using it for my DI container class, its so I can easily set new functions without having to edit the class, I edited it so the `get()` function returns the executed version of the function and it passes `$this` into the function so I can use the object scope. However, this answer provides me with an understanding of closures and magic methods so appreciated!

Comment: @KyleThomas nice ;) If you understand, documentate it, so others can understand it too :)

Comment: Thats true! Your head gets mangled with code so you cant word what your thinking haha! Plus im all selftaught so hopefully I can start blogging soon :D appreciate the help tho ppl @dbf

Answer (score 0):

Thanks too [@PeeHaa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/508666/peehaa), I finally fixed the issue.

When I am retrieving the function, it is still in its closure and has not been executed. Depending on your PHP versions you can do either:

```
$execute = $example->get('example')();
echo $execute;

echo $example->get('example')();
```